# Translation of “in” as “and”

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, translation-check, translation-explanation, preposition, conjunction

In one of his letters to Varro, Cicero says:

“Si hortum *in* bibliotheca habes, deerit nihil.”

I’ve found this translated as:

“If you have a garden *and* a library, you have everything you need” ([wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Cicero))

My understanding is that “in” can be translated as one of several prepositions (in, at, into, etc.); however, here it’s being translated as a conjunction. Is this correct? And are there any other examples of this?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The passage comes from [Cic. Fam. 9.4](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0009%3Abook%3D9%3Aletter%3D4), namely from a letter to Varro.

Apparently others have translated as you would expect:

> If you have a garden in your library, everything will be complete ([Shuckburgh, 1908](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0022%3Atext%3DF%3Abook%3D9%3Aletter%3D4))

Of course, having a garden in a library sounds weird, right? Shuckburgh himself adds his view on this on a footnote:

> Probably means (though it is a strange way of expressing it) a garden to sit and converse in, like philosophers in the Academy: the library being like Cicero's Tusculan gymnasium, round a court containing shrubs, etc. There is a similar reference to Cicero's villa at Cumae, Vol. i., p.253 (Q. Fr. 2.8).

Perhaps translating it as *and* tries to circumvent this weirdness by freely offering something that just sounds less strange.

Comment: Shakleton Bailey's translation in the Loeb edition agrees: "If you have a kitchen garden in your library we shall lack for nothing."